# How to pass arguments to initialize method from a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-push-notifications

I am using Push8 gem for Apple push notification which accepts .P8 certificates.The problem is that I have two bundle_id for two separate apps and need to send Push Notifications to both of them. The Push8 gem accepts bundle_id ENV['APN_BUNDLE_ID'] params automatically from the application.yml file. However, I want it to use ENV['APN_VENDOR_BUNDLE_ID'] as well for a different APP to send Push Notification.

my code to send Push notification is here

```
  def self.send_notification_ios(device_id, notification_id)
    send = Notification.where(id: notification_id).first
     if Rails.env == 'development'
        apn = P8push::Client.development
     else
        apn = P8push::Client.production
     end

    token = device_id
    notification = P8push::Notification.new(device: token)
    notification.alert = send.template.message % { txnid: send.order.txnid }
    notification.sound = 'sosumi.aiff'
    apn.push(notification)
    end
```

Here If the send.end_user_type is "User" I want to use the Bundle id APN_BUNDLE_ID as the topic, for rest as want to use APN_VENDOR_BUNDLE_ID. But I dont know how to pass APN_VENDOR_BUNDLE_ID as a param to initialize method in the client.rb file of the gem. Hence it always accepts APN_BUNDLE_ID as the topic and hence throws the error topic disallowed.

Here is the client.rb file for the gem:
https://github.com/andrewarrow/p8push/blob/master/lib/p8push/client.rb

The link for the gem is https://github.com/andrewarrow/p8push

Answer (score 1):

If the `initialize` method makes no accommodations for customizing that attribute you've got two choices: Monkey-patch it to make it do what you want, which is messy, or subclass it and use that instead.

The sub-class solution looks like this:

```
class UserAwareClient < P8Push::Client
  def self.development(user_type)
    client = self.new(user_type)
    client.jwt_uri = APPLE_DEVELOPMENT_JWT_URI
    client
  end

  def self.production(user_type)
    client = self.new(user_type)
    client.jwt_uri = APPLE_PRODUCTION_JWT_URI
    client
  end

  def initialize(user_type)
    # Initialize as the parent class would
    super

    # Then detect the user_type argument and decide how to configure it
    @private_key =
      case (user_type)
      when 'User'
        File.read(ENV['APN_PRIVATE_KEY'])
      else
        File.read(ENV['APN_VENDOR_BUNDLE_ID'])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you create that:

```
apn = UserAwareClient.development(user_type)
```

This gem could be made a lot more flexible with a few pull-requests to make your life easier, so consider that, too.